# Retrieving the most common keywords from a tsvector column

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I'm considering adding a tsvector column to an existing table that will hold possible search terms for multiple columns in that same table (e.g. the tsvector column will equal `to_tsvector(header || ' ' || body || ' ' || footer)`).  Before I decide to do so, one of my requirements is that I am able to find the most popular keywords amongst all records in the table.

Is there anything similar to tsquery that will find my the most popular keywords over all records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the [ts_stat](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-STATISTICS) FTS function is what you're after.