# How do I use Postgres full text search to get most frequent keywords?

Tags: postgresql

I want to use Postgres full text search feature to generate the list of the 10 most frequent keywords in a given column in my database, just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851065/retrieving-the-most-common-keywords-from-a-tsvector-column).
The point is that I can't get to the result with the given answer: using the link provided I was able to get to this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('select to_tsvector(''english'', ''a running  mobile elevator'')')
ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word
```

it returns:

```
"elev";1;1
"mobil";1;1
"run";1;1
```

The problem is that I want to build a Word Cloud from this result, so "elev" or "mobil" won't help me.

Is there any way I can avoid/undo the word stemming?

ps: actually I want to do that in Portuguese, so I cannot use any existing configuration that only works for english.

Comment: You'll need to build a new, separate fulltext index with the 'simple' configuration to use for your word cloud, since that won't do stemming etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issues.
I had to first create a dicitionary based on simple using the portuguese stopwords ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS ):

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.simple_dict (
    TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
    STOPWORDS = english
);
```

And then use it in the search configuration:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION tst (copy=simple);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION tst ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH public.simple_dict;
```

Then it worked:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('tst','indices');
```